# 100% width sliding multi-level ULs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a navigation system where I would like the parent `ul` and all children `uls` to span 100% width and when you click an `li` with a child `ul`, the parent slides off to the left and the child slides in from the right. Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.list-container ul > li.has-child').each(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').prepend('<li class="back">< Back</li>');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.list-container ul > li', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var children = $(this).find('ul');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('back')) {
      if (children.length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().css('left','-100%');
        $(this).find('ul > li').css('display','block');
        $(this).find('ul').css('left','100%');
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click','li.back', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('left','0');
    $(this).parent().css('left','200%');
  });
});
```

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.list-container {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}
ul {
  width:100%;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

li {
  padding:10px 0 10px 15px;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
  li.has-child:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:">";
    float:right;
    margin-right:15px;
  }
li > ul {
  display:block;
  left:200%;
  top:0;
}
li > ul > li {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="has-child">Test 1
      <ul>
        <li class="has-child">Test 1 sub-menu
          <ul>
            <li>Test 1 sub-sub-menu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test 1 sub-menu a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child">Test 2
      <ul>
        <li>Test 2 sub-menu</li>
        <li class="has-child">Test 2 sub-menu a
          <ul>
            <li>Test 2 sub-sub-menu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child">Test 3
      <ul>
        <li>Test 3 sub-menu</li>
        <li class="has-child">Test 3 sub-menu a
          <ul>
            <li>Test 3 sub-sub-menu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This code is working as intended for the first/second level of items, but once you try to click through to the 3rd level(ie "Test 1 sub-menu") it gets messed up. I realize now that it probably would have been better to use `divs` for this rather than `uls`, but can anyone suggest how to get this working without modifying the HTML structure? Open to completely changing the jQuery/CSS if there's a better way to accomplish this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This code is working as intended for the first/second level of items,
>   but once you try to click through to the 3rd level(ie "Test 1
>   sub-menu") it gets messed up.

That is because, you are shifting the `ul` by a constant `200%`, while the child `ul` gets shifted by a constant `+/-100%`. At the same time you reset the main `ul` at `0`. Apart from this when you show the menu using display block, you do not hide those back. While this works for the first-level, it breaks apart from second-level onward.

> I realize now that it probably would have been better to use divs for
>   this rather than uls

Yes, you would probably be better off with `div`s because it would be easier for you to handle those as against the hierarchical `ul`s. But then, `ul` would be more semantic for a hierarchical structure.

If you do not want to change the HTML structure, then the easiest and best bet for you would be to specify the `level` each sub-menu is in. This can be done by simply adding a `data-` attribute on each `li` that has further sub-items and you can get rid of the `.has-child` class. Once you have the levels defined in the `data-` attributes, you can use those to shift each level by a corresponding factor.

Below is a crude demo. Please note that although you've tagged this with `jQuery`, I created this demo in plain old vanila JavaScript because that is easier and faster for me. You may convert this to jQuery if you wish, but otherwise this should work as-is without any problems.

**Demo Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/euLzo2dg/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```js
// keep things outside the global scope
(function (window, document) {
  var attachTo = document.getElementsByClassName('list-container')[0];
  prepareNav(attachTo); // attach nav to the div

  function prepareNav(nav) { 
    // prepare nav by creating back links, setting styles, and click handler
    var 
      navBar = nav.firstElementChild, 
      navElems = nav.querySelectorAll('li[data-level] > ul')
    ;
    for (i=0; i < navElems.length; i++) { 
      var backLink = document.createElement('li');
      backLink.className = 'back';
      backLink.textContent = '\u3008' + ' Back';
      navElems[i].insertBefore(backLink, navElems[i].firstElementChild);
    } 
    navBar.style.left = '0%';
    nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      startNav(e, navBar, navElems);
    }, false);
  }

  function startNav(e, navBar, navElems) { 
    // click handler
    if (e.target.dataset && e.target.dataset.level) { 
      // move main ul by negative multiples of level
      navBar.style.left = -(e.target.dataset.level * 100) + '%';
      // reset all menus by hiding those
      [].forEach.call(navElems, function(ne) { ne.classList.remove('show'); }); 
      // show the parent menu
      e.target.parentNode.classList.add('show');
      // show the current menu
      e.target.firstElementChild.classList.add('show');
    }
    if (e.target.className === 'back') { 
      // move back the main ul by 100 (not to 100)
      var leftPos = parseInt(navBar.style.left);
      navBar.style.left = (leftPos + 100) + '%';
    }
  } 
 
})(window, document);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif; }
html, body { height:100%; }
.list-container { 
  overflow: hidden; position: relative; 
  width: 100%; min-height: 128px; 
}
.list-container ul {
  width: 100%; background-color: #eee;
  list-style-type: none; 
  position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.list-container li {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px; 
  cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #aaa; 
}
.list-container li:first-child { border-bottom: none; }
.list-container li:last-child { border-top: none; }
.list-container li.back + li:last-child { border-top: 1px solid #aaa;  }
.list-container li[data-level]::after {
  display: inline-block; content: '\003009';
  float: right; margin-right: 15px;
}
.list-container li[data-level]:hover, 
.list-container li.back:hover { background-color: #ddd; }
.list-container li[data-level] > ul { left: 100%; top: 0; display: none; }
.list-container li[data-level] > ul.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <ul>
    <li data-level="1">Test 1
      <ul>
        <li data-level="2">Test 1 sub-menu
          <ul>
            <li>Test 1 sub-sub-menu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test 1 sub-menu a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-level="1">Test 2
      <ul>
        <li>Test 2 sub-menu</li>
        <li data-level="2">Test 2 sub-menu a
          <ul>
            <li>Test 2 sub-sub-menu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-level="1">Test 3
      <ul>
        <li>Test 3 sub-menu</li>
        <li data-level="2">Test 3 sub-menu a
          <ul>
            <li>Test 3 sub-sub-menu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you for the detailed explanation, very helpful!